# snmpget "No such object available on this agent at this OID"

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, oid, mib

I have been working on trying to get a value with a custom MIB through SNMP

This is my custom MIB:

```
MY-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, Integer32, enterprises
        FROM SNMPv2-SMI
;

psutest MODULE-IDENTITY
    LAST-UPDATED    "201411250000Z"
    ORGANIZATION    "UW - System"
    CONTACT-INFO    "Bob"
    DESCRIPTION     "MIB for project"

    ::={ enterprises 214}

currentScalar       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { psutest 2}
voltageScalar       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { psutest 3}

currentScalar OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION  "A simple object that holds the current current as a simple integer"

    ::= { psutest 2}

voltageScalar OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION  "A simple object that holds the current voltage reading as a single integer"

    ::= { psutest 3}

END
```

Now when I do `snmpget -v2c -c public localhost currentScalar.0` it returns `MY-MIB::currentScalar.0 = No Such Object available on this agetn at this OID`.  I've already loaded the MIB by going through the [tutorial here on the Net-snmp webiste](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS)  [Looking through this example MIB from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914975.aspx), I feel like I might be doing somethign wrong with the lines:

```
currentScalar       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { psutest 2}
voltageScalar       OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { psutest 3}
```

My snmpd.conf file is pretty basic:

```
agentAddress udp:161

view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view systemonly included .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

rocommunity public efault .1.3.6.1
...
some system information stuff and active monitoring I haven't touched 
...

extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.214.2 /home/pi/networking/supply.sh

master agentx
```

Am I missing an entire object definition or something?

Comment: Try with `snmpget -m ALL -v2c -c public localhost currentScalar.0`

Comment: @JannePikkarainen It returns the same error after looking through other mibs, printing out other things like: `Bad operator (INTEGER): At line 73 in /usr/share/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-PDU` and `Undefined OBJECT-GROPU (diffServMultiFieldClfrNextFree): At line 2157 in /usr/share/mibs/ietf/IPSEC-SPD-MIB` and such

Comment: @Funkyguy Hey bro did you find the solution for it? I'm stuck with the same from a couple of weeks.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava hey man, I'm sorry but I don't think I ever did. I'm pretty sure I just ended up submitting the theory of operation to my professor and left it at that.

Comment: oh! that's horrible. Even I'm trying but no luck yet. anyways all the best buddy. and thanks for replying:)